# Whether to use context bound or implicit ev in Scala

Tags: scala

According to the style guide - is there a rule of thumb what one should use for typeclasses in Scala - `context bound` or `implicit ev` notation?

These two examples do the same

Context bound has more concise function signature, but requires `val` evaluation with `implicitly` call:

```
def empty[T: Monoid, M[_] : Monad]: M[T] = {
    val M = implicitly[Monad[M]]
    val T = implicitly[Monoid[T]]
    M.point(T.zero)
}
```

The `implicit ev` approach automatically inserts typeclasses into function parameters but pollutes method signature:

```
def empty[T, M[_]](implicit T: Monoid[T], M: Monad[M]): M[T] = {
  M.point(T.zero)
}
```

Most of the libraries I've checked (e.g. `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.2"`) use `implicit ev`

What are you using and why?

Answer (score 3):

This is very opinion-based, but one pratical reason for using an implicit parameter list directly is that you perform fewer implicit searches.

When you do

```
def empty[T: Monoid, M[_] : Monad]: M[T] = {
  val M = implicitly[Monad[M]]
  val T = implicitly[Monoid[T]]
  M.point(T.zero)
}
```

this gets desugared by the compiler into

```
def empty[T, M[_]](implicit ev1: Monoid[T], ev2: Monad[M]): M[T] = {
  val M = implicitly[Monad[M]]
  val T = implicitly[Monoid[T]]
  M.point(T.zero)
}
```

so now the `implicitly` method needs to do another implicit search to find `ev1` and `ev2` in scope.

It's very unlikely that this has a noticeable runtime overhead, but it may affect your compile time performance in some cases.

If instead you do

```
def empty[T, M[_]](implicit T: Monoid[T], M: Monad[M]): M[T] =
  M.point(T.zero)
```

you're directly accessing `M` and `T` from the first implicit search.

Also (and this is my personal opinion) I prefer the body to be shorter, at the price of some boilerplate in the signature.

Most libraries I know that make heavy use of implicit parameters use this style whenever they need to access the instance, so I guess I simply became more familiar with the notation.

---

Bonus, if you decide for the context bound anyway, it's usually a good idea to provide an `apply` method on the typeclass that searches for the implicit instance. This allows you to write

```
def empty[T: Monoid, M[_]: Monad]: M[T] = {
  Monad[M].point(Monoid[T].zero)
}
```

More info on this technique here: https://blog.buildo.io/elegant-retrieval-of-type-class-instances-in-scala-32a524bbd0a7

Comment: I completely agree, but I'd like to add a small precision: the implicit search is performed by the compiler at compile time, so there is absolutely no runtime performance hit. Conclusion: it is really as you say `opinion-based`.

Comment: no runtime performance hit, but compile-time performance is a bit problem in scala code-bases, so I always tend to keep an eye on it ;) Also there may be a little runtime overhead because you're doing one extra method call (to `implicitly`), but the JVM will probably inline that

Comment: Thank you! Really nice approach with an `apply` method, checked the article. Didn't find in `scalaz` typeclasses though

Comment: That's unfortunate as it's a conveniente trick. cats typeclasses use it (via simulacrum) and it's a real keystroke saver

Comment: @EugeneZhulkov it is available in scalaz, at least in 7.2.x (see e.g. [Monoid companion object](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monoid.scala#L86))

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov got it!

Comment: I did a quick test, and Gabriele is right about potential runtime overhead, which is a bit of a surprise.  `implicitly` is annotated `@inline`, but the Scala compiler does not seem to inline it in the generated byte code.  So inlining would have to be done by the JIT.  Dotty's `inline` keyword should fix that.

Answer (score 3):

One caveat you need to be aware of when working with `implicitly` is when using dependently typed functions. I'll quote from the book "The type astronauts guide to shapeless". It looks at the `Last` type class from Shapeless which retrieves the last type of an `HList`:

```
package shapeless.ops.hlist

trait Last[L <: HList] {
  type Out
  def apply(in: L): Out
}
```

And says:

> The implicitly method from scala.Predef has this behaviour (this
>   behavior means losing the inner type member information). Compare the
>   type of an instance of Last summoned with implicitly:

```
implicitly[Last[String :: Int :: HNil]]
res6: shapeless.ops.hlist.Last[shapeless.::[String,shapeless
      .::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]] = shapeless.ops.hlist$Last$$anon$34@20bd5df0
```

> to the type of an instance summoned with Last.apply:

```
Last[String :: Int :: HNil]
res7: shapeless.ops.hlist.Last[shapeless.::[String,shapeless
      .::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]]{type Out = Int} = shapeless.ops.hlist$Last$$anon$34@4ac2f6f
```

The type summoned by implicitly has no `Out` type member, that is an important caveat and generally why you would use the summoner pattern which doesn't use context bounds and `implicitly`.

---

Other than that, generally I find that it is a matter of style. Yes, `implicitly` might slightly increase compile times, but if you have an implicit rich application you'll most likely not "feel" the difference between the two at compile time.

And on a more personal note, sometimes writing `implicitly[M[T]]` feels "uglier" than making the method signature a bit longer, and might be clearer to the reader when you declare the implicit explicitly with a named field.

Comment: thank you! will check the book, didn't know about this caveat

Comment: @EugeneZhulkov Great book in general for type level programming and introduction to Shapeless.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on top of doing the same, your 2 examples *are* the same. Context bounds is just syntactic sugar for adding implicit parameters.

I am being opportunistic, using context bound as much as I can i.e., when I don't already have implicit function parameters. When I already have some, it is impossible to use context bound and I have no other choice but adding to the implicit parameter list.

Note that you don't need to define `val`s as you did, this works just fine (but I think you should go for what makes the code easier to read):

```
def empty[T: Monoid, M[_] : Monad]: M[T] = {
  implicitly[Monad[M]].point(implicitly[Monoid[T]].zero)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand how it works, the question was about code style only. It's a matter of taste, I believe, but wanted to check with community :)

Answer (score 1):

FP libraries usually give you syntax extensions for typeclasses:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
def empty[T: Monoid, M[_]: Monad]: M[T] = mzero[T].point[M]
```

I use this style as much as possible. This gives me syntax consistent with standard library methods and also lets me write `for`-comprehensions over generic `Functor`s / `Monad`s

---

If not possible, I use special `apply` on companion object:

```
import cats._, implicits._ // no mzero in cats
def empty[T: Monoid, M[_]: Monad]: M[T] = Monoid[T].empty.pure[M]
```

I use [simulacrum](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) to provide these for my own typeclasses.

---

I resort to `implicit ev` syntax for cases where context bound is not enough (e.g. multiple type parameters)

Comment: Oh thank you! totally forgot about `mzero[T].point[M]`. But my question was more general, not only about fp libraries but about all typeclasses.

Comment: @EugeneZhulkov, yeah, I described my preferences and there's no style guide for that. A lot of libraries actually provide syntactical enrichments (e.g. operators in `spire`) or regular methods with implicit parameters (e.g. `Json.toJson(instance)` in `play-json`) allowing you to use context bounds, so both function definition and implementation are short and readable. And for custom ones, it's about adding a single annotation to a trait.